# jquery/jquery ui: find each span add class to single span being dragged

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery

I'm trying to make it so only the span that is being dragged has a class added, so far I have this but but it adds the class to all span's ...

```
$(function() {

 $('span').draggable();

  $('#container, #board').droppable({
    tolerance : 'touch',
         over : function() {

    $('li').each(function() {
     $(this).find('span').addClass('over');
    });             

},
    drop : function() {
    $('li').each(function() {
     $(this).find('span').removeClass('over');          
}); 

      }
   });
});
```

Here's the he HTML (if that helps)

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="board">
  <ul>
   <li class="foo1"><span class="p1"></span></li>
   <li class="foo2"><span class="p1"></span></li>
   <li class="foo1"><span class="p1"></span></li>
   <li class="foo2"><span class="p1"></span></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the start event to add the class to the element being dragged.

```
$('span').draggable({
   start: function(event, ui) {
      $(event.target).addClass('over');
   }
});
```

and to remove it again when no longer dragged simply add a handler to the stop event as well

```
$('span').draggable({
   start: function(event, ui) {
      $(event.target).addClass('over');
   },
   stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(event.target).removeClass('over');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `each()`, just do `$(this)`, which refers to the current element, and it should work:

```
over : function() {
    $(this).find('span').addClass('over');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

 $('span').draggable();

  $('#container, #board').droppable({
    tolerance : 'touch',
    over : function() {
       $(this).find('li span').addClass('over');
    },
    drop : function() {
       $(this).find('li span').removeClass('over');          
    }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#container, #board').droppable({
    tolerance : 'touch',
         over : function(e, elem) { // Params
                // here is the original element we move
                $(elem.draggable).find('span').addClass("over"); 


},
    drop : function(e, elem) {
              // 
              $(elem.draggable).find('span').removeClass('over');
```

however if you dont use original Dom when it is been dragging (ie. {helper: "clone" }), elem.draggable wont affect your helper. thats write your .draggable code here... 
and also you can try "elem.helper"